# How to make component global in Angular 2?

Tags: angular, typescript

I tried to make component as global. But it returns me an error:

```
Uncaught Error: Can't export directive LanguageComponent from SharedModule as it was neither declared nor imported!
```

So, I added component to shareModule as:

```
exports: [
    LoaderComponent,
    LanguageComponent
  ]
```

Also I tried to add component to core.module as diclaration. It did not help.

**ShareModule is:**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { LoaderComponent } from './loader/loader.component';
import {LanguageComponent} from "../language/language.component";
import {HiderPipe} from "../pipes/Hider";

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    LanguageComponent,
    LoaderComponent,
    HiderPipe
  ],
  exports: [
    LoaderComponent,
    LanguageComponent,
    HiderPipe

  ]
})
export class SharedModule { }
```

This module is imported only in main `core.module` as:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [

    SharedModule
  ],
```

Comment: How would adding it to the exports make it declared or imported? How would declaring it in the core module help with the shared module? Did you read the message? Please give a [mcve].

Comment: I try to provide all information that I have :) I added ShareModule in question now

Comment: Please, see question again

Comment: So what precisely don't you understand? The message tells you exactly what the problem is, and makes two suggestions for fixing it. Did you try either of them? What happened?

Comment: I can not find where it was imported before. I really can not got it

Comment: *"imported before"* - before what? How could we tell you that from what you've posted anyway? Just *add it to the declarations*, as the compiler has already told you to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make a component available to the module which imports the `SharedModule`, you have to add the `LanguageComponent` to the `declarations` field of your `SharedModule` and to the `exports` field.

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    // ...
  ],
  declarations: [
    // ...
    LanguageComponent
  ],
  exports: [
    // ...
    LanguageComponent
  ]
})
export class SharedModule {
  // ...
}
```

As the error stated, you missed to add it to the declarations field:

> Uncaught Error: Can't export directive **LanguageComponent** from **SharedModule** as it was neither **declared** nor **imported**

*Or if you `LanguageComponent` is already part of another module (for example: `LanguageModule`), you have to import that module and you can also reexport that module.*

---

To use the component in another component which is part of another module, for example `AppModule`, you have to add the `SharedModule` to the import field of that module.

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    // ...
    SharedModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    // ...
  ],
  exports: [
    // ...
  ]
})
export class AppModule {
  // ...
}
```

And use it inside your component's template via the selector. See also the Feature Module section at the [**docs**](https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule#feature-modules).

Comment: Wait, will try to do

Comment: Then how to use this in others components? Directly in template it i should to add declaration meta in component description?

Comment: Can you explain how to use pipes as global too? And I will accept your answer :)

Comment: I tried to add pipe as you wrote above, but I get this: `Uncaught Error: Unexpected pipe 'HiderPipe' imported by the module 'SharedModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation.`

Comment: For pipe's it works the same, just add the pipe to the `declarations` and `exports` field of the `SharedModule`. An example can be found at the [**docs**](https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule#add-the-contactmodule).

Comment: I strongly recommend that you should go through the [**tutorial**](https://angular.io/tutorial) section, because it seems like you don't know how the angular module system is  actually working.

Comment: Problem is in another. I did that you recommend me. Just I still get error: `Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
'language-component' is not a known element:
1. If 'language-component' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.`

Comment: Does the component, in which template you're trying to use the `language-component`, belongs to a module (is part of the `declarations` field) which imports the `SharedModule`? Because that's what the error is saying.

Comment: Yes, exactly it is component that depends by app.module, and app.module includes share.module

Answer (score 1):

You also need to add in declarations array.

```
declarations:[LanguageComponent]
```

Comment: Where to add that?

Comment: In your SharedModule